# Kernel density estimation for noisy samples with known non-iid noise

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I'm interested in the following variant of the usual one-dimensional density-estimation problem:

I wish to estimate some unknown density $\rho$. There are iid samples $Y_{1},\ldots,Y_{n} \sim \rho$, but I don't get to see them. Instead, let $\epsilon_{1},\ldots,\epsilon_{n}$ be iid standard Gaussians, let $\sigma_{1},\ldots,\sigma_{n}$ be sampled from a "nice" distribution $f$, and let $X_{j} = Y_{j} + \sigma_{j} \epsilon_{j}$.

I assume that I get to see the sequence $(X_{j}, \epsilon_{j})$ (but nothing else) and wish to estimate $\rho$.

I don't care overly much about the norm in which I estimate $\rho$ or the distribution $f$. To make a concrete problem, I'd certainly be happy for a solution that worked for the usual MISE norm and the $Uniform[0,1]$ for $f$.

I'm vaguely aware of work on "iterated" estimates, such as the paper "Iterative density estimation from contaminated observations." This doesn't quite solve the problem I'm interested in, but it is the closest that I've found.